# Circuit protection with TVS and polyfuse

Tags: surge-protection, tvs, polyfuse

I have a 36V system that has to be protected against 1000V surges as described by IEC61000-4-5. Some SMC TVS diodes are rated for this exact purpose and are able to conduct the surge pulses without damage.

Problem solved?

However: In many posts here and elsewhere a polyfuse is placed in front of the TVS diode. The reasoning being that you then get DC overvoltage protection, and even reverse polarity protection if the TVS is uni-directional. But as far as I can tell no polyfuse on the marked is rated for the currents or the voltages involved with transient protection.
Why is this such a popular circuit? A TVS diode's purpose is to conduct high energy pulses, but that purpose is invalidated by the introduction of a polyfuse.

Secondly: It therefore seems impossible to get both DC overvoltage and transient overvoltage protection at the same time. DC overvoltage will destroy a TVS, transient high voltage will destroy a polyfuse.  Are there other components that can be used?

Comment: I don't think it's a very popular circuit so please add a few links that indicate its popularity and add an image of the schematic to the question.

Comment: you could use the well known SCR crowbar as a DC overvoltage protection. It *will* blow a fuse/trigger the polyfuse but that's often the right response

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio perhaps in some cases, however having a chance that a transient will "brick" the device is in this case quite unacceptable. It still has the same problem though: the surge currents will be conducted trough a polyfuse, something they are not rated for.